# Creating an array of objects in Logstash

Tags: logstash

Lets say in a given event i have 4 fields
psn1_name (holding the value “A”),
psn1_age (holding the value 10),
psn2_name (holding the value “B”),
psn2_age (holding the value 20)
I want to create a field person such that person is of the following structure

person = [
{
“name”:“A”
,“age”:10
},
{
“name”:“B”
,“age”:20
}
]

Can someone please suggest how to achieve this in the filter section of my logstash configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware from logstash 5 the events API has changed (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-api.html).

```
filter {
  ruby {
        code => '
          event.set("person", [{"name" => event.get("psn1_name"), "age" => event.get("psn1_age")}, {"name" => event.get("psn2_name"), "age" => event.get("psn2_age")}])
        '
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["psn1_name", "psn1_age", "psn2_name", "psn2_age"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you help me with this?stackoverflow.com/questions/62661091/… – Max just now   Edit   Delete

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ruby filter to handle your data in a more granular way.
This is untested, but should help you find your solution:

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
                event['person'] = [{"name" => event['psn1_name'], "age" => event['psn1_age']},{"name" => event['psn2_name'], "age" => event['psn2_age']}]
        "
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you help me with this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62661091/aggregate-multiple-recursive-logstash