# aggregate multiple recursive logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-jdbc

I am using logstash with input jdbc, and would like to embed one object inside another with aggregate.
How can I use add recursive?

Ie add an object inside another object?

This would be an example:

```
{
  "_index": "my-index",
  "_type": "test",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": "1",
    "properties": {
      "nested_1": [
        {
          "A": 0,
          "B": "true",
          "C": "PEREZ, MATIAS  ROGELIO Y/O",
          "Nested_2": [
            {
              "Z1": "true",
              "Z2": "99999"
            }
        },
        {
          "A": 0,
          "B": "true",
          "C": "SALVADOR MATIAS ROMERO",
          "Nested_2": [
            {
              "Z1": "true",
              "Z2": "99999"
            }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using something like that but it doesn't work

```
aggregate {
  task_id => "%{id}"
  code => "
      map['id'] = event.get('id')
      
      map['nested_1_list'] ||= []
      map['nested_1'] ||= []
      if (event.get('id') != nil)
        if !( map['nested_1_list'].include?event.get('id') ) 
          map['nested_1_list'] << event.get('id')
 
          map['nested_1'] << {
            'A' => event.get('a'),                             
            'B' => event.get('b'),
            'C' => event.get('c'),
            
             map['nested_2_list'] ||= []
              map['nested_2'] ||= []
              if (event.get('id_2') != nil)
                if !( map['nested_2_list'].include?event.get('id_2') ) 
                  map['nested_2_list'] << event.get('id_2')
         
                  map['nested_2'] << {
                    'Z1' => event.get('z1'), 
                    'Z2' => event.get('z2')
                  }
                end
              end
          }
        end
      end
       
      event.cancel()
  "
  push_previous_map_as_event => true
  timeout => 3

}
```

Any idea how to implement this?........................
..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what I did was, generate the JSON from the input, that is, from a stored procedure that is consumed from a view (vw) from the input statement of logstash.

Once consumed, I process it as json and I already have that json to work as one more variable.

```
# Convierto el string a json real (quita comillas y barras invertidas)
        ruby {
            code => "
                require 'json'
                json_value = JSON.parse(event.get('field_db').to_s)
                event.set('field_convert_to_json',json_value)
            "
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this. Note This will be applicable only when you want to have a single object and not an array of object.
Please do visit my blog for other formats.
https://xyzcoder.github.io/2020/07/29/indexing-documents-using-logstash-and-python.html

```
input {
    jdbc {
           jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/javalib/mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre11.jar"
           jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
           jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://host.docker.internal;database=StackOverflow2010;user=pavan;password=pavankumar@123"
           jdbc_user => "pavan"
           jdbc_password => "pavankumar@123"
           statement => "select top 500 p.Id as PostId,p.AcceptedAnswerId,p.AnswerCount,p.Body,u.Id as userid,u.DisplayName,u.Location
                        from StackOverflow2010.dbo.Posts p inner join StackOverflow2010.dbo.Users u
                        on p.OwnerUserId=u.Id"
        }
}

filter {
    aggregate {
        task_id => "%{postid}"
        code => "
            map['postid'] = event.get('postid')
            map['accepted_answer_id'] = event.get('acceptedanswerid')
            map['answer_count'] = event.get('answercount')
            map['body'] = event.get('body')
            map['user'] = {
                'id' => event.get('userid'),
                'displayname' => event.get('displayname'),
                'location' => event.get('location')
            }
            map['user']['test'] = {
                    'test_body' => event.get('postid')
                }
        event.cancel()"
        push_previous_map_as_event => true
        timeout => 30
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200", "http://elasticsearch:9200"]
        index => "stackoverflow_top"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

and my output is

```
{
        "_index" : "stackoverflow_top",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "S8WEmnMBrXsRTNbKO0JJ",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@version" : "1",
          "body" : """<p>How do I store binary data in <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL" rel="noreferrer">MySQL</a>?</p>
""",
          "@timestamp" : "2020-07-29T12:20:22.649Z",
          "answer_count" : 10,
          "user" : {
            "displayname" : "Geoff Dalgas",
            "location" : "Corvallis, OR",
            "test" : {
              "test_body" : 17
            },
            "id" : 2
          },
          "postid" : 17,
          "accepted_answer_id" : 26
        }
```

Here test object is nested into the user object