# How to configure logstash file to make nested object inside another nested filed from sql query

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, logstash, plpgsql, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am new in Elasticsearch and logstash and I have an issue with nested objects.
So what I want to ask is how can I create index with multiple nested fields inside another nested fields.

How can I build the data inside logstash file configuration  from data from postgres to index something like below inside elasticsearch?

For example, I have a Product which have raw materials and raw materials have substances

```
product {
 id: 1,
 name: "name",
 raw_materials: [{
  id: 1,
  name: "raw_name",
  substances: [{
    id: 1,
    name: "sub_name",
  }]
 }]
}
```

Help me please

Comment: Do you still have this question? I find a solution to share?

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have this question? I find a solution to share?
My solution at the time was to generate, in this case for its field "substances", a json. That is, my query in posgresql returned: id, raw_materials, json {substances}

[aggregate multiple recursive logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62661091/aggregate-multiple-recursive-logstash/63153728#63153728)